# Any tutorials for developing chatbots?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, nlp, chatbot

As a engineering student, I would like to make a chat bot using python. So, I searched a lot but couldn't really find stuff that would teach me or give me some concrete information to build a intelligent chat bot.

I would like to make a chatbot that gives human-like responses (Simply like a friend chatting with you). I am currently expecting it to be as just a software on my laptop (would like to implement in IM, IRC or websites later).

So, I am looking for a tutorial/ any other information which would certainly help me to get my project done.

Comment: First, when you say "chatbot", how do you want to be able to interact with this bot? On a website, on IRC, on MSN, Jabber, AIM? Second, what do you want the bot to be able to do? Will it just recognise certain words in text and respond with automatic responses (e.g. if you said "Bot, wiki potato" it would respond with a link to the Wikipedia page for "potato"), or do you want some sort of human-like response? I'd suggest figuring out the answers to these before going further.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. Here is what I am looking to make. I am first looking to make a chatbot that give human like responses..(Just a simple chat). I just want it to be as a software on my PC (Right now, i don't want to get into IRC's or websites or any IM)

Comment: You can have a look at: http://rodic.fr/blog/python-chatbot-1/

Comment: I use this for fast chatbot prototypes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h53SjVGMwos

Comment: I've written a very basic tutorial on using Rasa NLU with Node-RED for chatbot development. It's very friendly to developers and non-developers. https://blog.spg.ai/build-a-chatbot-with-rasa-nlu-dc2bfb55edb2

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can read a nice introduction to various techniques used to design chatbots here: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/6305/beyond_fa%C3%A7ade_pattern_matching_.php

Also, here are a few useful links:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20120320060043/
- http://ai-programming.com/bot_tutorial.htm
- http://www.alicebot.org/be.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chatterbots
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36106/Chatbot-Tutorial
- http://www.slideshare.net/amyiris/ai-and-python-developing-a-conversational-interface-using-python

The [Natural Language Toolkit (python)](http://www.nltk.org) implements a few chatbots: http://nltk.github.com/api/nltk.chat.html

Simple pipeline architecture for a spoken dialogue system from the book [Natural Language Processing with Python - Analyzing Text with the Natural Language Toolkit](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516499.do) By Steven Bird, Ewan Klein, Edward Loper:

[image]

Comment: +1 Just a *few* links. :D

Comment: `http://ai-programming.com/bot_tutorial.htm` is a dead link

Comment: @TasdikRahman :( SE should have some link mirroring system, as Wikipedia does.

Comment: you can visit https://playground.pandorabots.com/en/tutorial/ . Its very easy tutorial to get you started in minutes. Instead of pandorabot, use your own interpreter. Concepts are same.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20120320060043/ ,
http://ai-programming.com/bot_tutorial.htm ,
http://www.alicebot.org/be.html 
404 now :(

Answer (score 16):

The two places I would start with are [how cleverbot works [part of a podcast]](http://www.radiolab.org/2011/may/31/) and then go through the [Natural Language Toolkit Book](http://www.nltk.org/book) to learn about the algorithms to use. (NLTK uses python, but the book is also a python tutorial)