# permutations and variations for chatbot user intents

Tags: chatbot

(first time posting, be nice. Also, I'm learning how to code, so I may not ask this question in the right way, be nice) I'm designing a chatbot and I'm having trouble finding a solution that creates all the possible permutations and variations for how a user would ask a question or make a request.  For example, if a user wants to know the weather they could ask "Wha't the weather?" or "Will it be sunny tomorrow?" or, or, or.  Any resources you could point me to will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As @CameronBuck pointed out, it is a complex task, and not a very specific problem. There is hardly anything like a *correct answer* to your question, so the  question is not fit for a Q/A-portal as StackOverflow. You should start reading about this topic, and then start developing. During both stages you might face very specific problems - either understanding what you read or implementing what you thought. Those problems will be very welcome on this site. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is called natural language processing and is not trivial. I wouldn't recommend working on something as complex as this for a beginner. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing

I found a couple threads where people wanted to do the same thing.

[Any tutorials for developing chatbots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706769/any-tutorials-for-developing-chatbots)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132165/programming-a-chatterbot-understanding-language

But yeah, this isn't easy.