# How do I build a chatbot interface to a database in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, chatbot, aiml

Database queries can be highly technical. I wish to build a Python chatbot to query a database/csv data-frame. I do not wish to use any ready API services as the data could be proprietary.

Sample example: with internal HR bot employees can ask various queries about their own records, leave balances etc.

Not sure how AIML based pure python chatbot can do this? For a question/category(AIML) on leave-balance, how will it fire a database/data-frame query and put the answer back as response/template(AIML).

Any open-source examples with or without AIML?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure a start would be to write some code. Also, perhaps, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706769/any-tutorials-for-developing-chatbots) might help?

Answer (score 0):

In the link provided by @n-wouda a number of good references to creation of chatbots have been provided. That said, if you prefer a little more accessible and concrete direction then I'd recommend to go to DevDungeon Article: [AI Chat Bot in Python with AIML](http://www.devdungeon.com/content/ai-chat-bot-python-aiml) which uses the Python module aiml that can be downloaded using pip

```
pip install aiml
```